# Resource monitor

Tags: 12.04, server, vps

I have a VPS that I have just purchased and I want to start monitoring the resources as I refuse to pay for the additional feature on the management tool to do that.

I wondered if there is something out there that can log resource usage (CPU, Mem, Disk) that just sits in the background logging and if resources get too hi then notify me. Is this something I should write in bash and run as a cron job??

I just want something light that wont be resource hungry.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want web interface - try munin it works quite good out of the box, for cli users i'd recommend `atop` utility.

By default `atop` will write system info to log in `/var/log/atop/atop_YYYYMMDD` or to `/var/log/atop.log` (depending on version) with 10 minutes resolution, only way to change it now is to edit atop's init script :(

Reports for atop can be generated with `atopsar`.

Note that any monitoring installed on the same host it's watching will not be available in case of severe problems on that host (and when you'll probably need it most).